# Azure API: How to get Azure Public images

Tags: azure

I will use public image to create VM, but i cant get public images list form Azure API, So how to get Azure public images , which url we can use?

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineimages/list) what you want to find?

Comment: Looks like it's right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this URL to get a list of all virtual machine image versions for the specified location, publisher, offer, and SKU.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/publishers/{publisherName}/artifacttypes/vmimage/offers/{offer}/skus/{skus}/versions?api-version=2017-12-01
```

References: [Virtual Machine Images - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineimages/list)